# Is there a way to redirect Coqide messages and errors to the same output?

Tags: coq, coqide

I have a tactic whose expected behavior is to output an error message, and I want to run it in batch mode on a series of goals and for each goal, I want to record the goal and the error message from the tactic. It seems like I can't do this with `coqc` since it will not continue on failure, so I'm doing this on Coqide. The closest I've been able to come to a solution is to have my file to have goals that look like this:

```
Theorem/Lemma blah.
Proof. Show. my_tactic. Admitted.
```

The first problem with this is that `Show` doesn't retain the proof goals in the `Messages` tab of Coqide through the run of the file, and the second is that while the output of the tactic is retained in the `Errors` tab, I am not able to copy it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the "Fail" command.  This is with 8.13 (with master the contexts and errors are not correctly interleaved).  I didn't try 8.14-8.17.  You need to run all of the input with "run to end" or "run to cursor"; single stepping will block you at the first error:

[Fail command example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vudJ9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Jim's solution is nice, you can also use [coq-lsp](https://github.com/ejgallego/coq-lsp) which will emit a diagnostic for the error (and goal info if you need it) but continue checking the document.